# Ordinal Hinge Loss Derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to [This paper](https://courses2.cit.cornell.edu/mru8/doc/udell15_pca_dataframe.pdf), the ordinal hinge loss can be defined as follows in (4). I believe that 'a' is the true value and 'u' is the predicted one.

My question is if it is possible to re-write this so that the second derivative of the function with respect to 'u' is not zero?

[image]